# How can i send a message to a client after an amount of time, in c server

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, server, timer

I'm working with C multithread server, and I want to send a message to all the connected clients, after n seconds. I tried with a separate thread and sleep, but it doesn't seem to work correctly. I thought to use an alarm, but I'm not really sure how to do it.

**This is what I'm doing right now**

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]){

    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);      
    signal(SIGINT, signalHandler);
    signal(SIGTSTP , signalHandler);
    pthread_t timer_thread;
    pthread_create(&timer_thread,NULL,timer_handler,NULL);
    pthread_detach(timer_thread);
    init_socket(port);

    return 0;
}
```

**Thread handler**

```
void *timer_handler(void *args){
    while(true){
        sleep(1);
        printf("Tempo indeterminato\n");
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a thread-safe way to communicate with your threads?  For example each thread might have a FIFO queue of incoming events, access to which is serialized by a mutex, and each thread periodically (on response to a trigger of some sort) checks its queue, removed any events that are in it, and handles those events.  In that scenario, your timer-thread could post a "please-send-this-message" event to each of the threads' incoming-events-queues, and each thread would then respond to the event by sending the specified data to its client's socket.

Comment: Btw if the above seems elaborate, it is -- but multithreading is an elaborate way to implement a server, especially if the server requires communication between threads.  You could alternatively switch to a single-threaded model, in which one thread handles all of your clients, and then just use the timeout feature of `select()` or `poll()` to do the same thing (with no event-queues of mutexes required since there is only one thread).  Of course a single-threaded server has its own complexities to deal with.